# Sliding window over an image to extract local Fourier modes

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, fft

I would like to extract the local Fourier modes from a binary image (ones and zeros), so if the image is, let's say, (1000,1000), I would like to take a Fourier transforms of windows of (30,30). How can I make this windows without making many copies of the data?

Comment: Isn't this possible with scipy.ndimage.generic_filter, providing the fft function as filter function?

Answer (score 1):

This is an excellent scenario for `as_strided`:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided
>>> a = np.arange(4*4).reshape(4,4)
>>> ws = (2,2) # shape of the elements on which you want to perform the operation (e.g. Fourier Transform)
>>> a_view = as_strided(a, shape=(a.shape[0] - ws[0] + 1, a.shape[1] - ws[1] + 1) + ws, strides=a.strides*2)
>>> a
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15]])
>>> a_view[0,0]
array([[0, 1],
       [4, 5]])
>>> a_view[0,1]  # move one window to the right
array([[1, 2],
       [5, 6]])
>>> a_view[1,1]  # move one window down from previous
array([[ 5,  6],
       [ 9, 10]])
```

This [blog entry](https://chintaksheth.wordpress.com/2013/07/31/numpy-the-tricks-of-the-trade-part-ii/) shows the same, but it is nice to study if you want another example.

With that view, you can easily [operate on the last two axes](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fft.fft2.html#numpy.fft.fft2) of the array (most functions in numpy and scipy that operate in 2 dimensions work on the last two axes by default):

```
>>> np.fft.fft2(a_view)
>>> a_view.sum(axis=(-2,-1)) # more visually understandable example (added in numpy version 1.7.0)
array([[10, 14, 18],
       [26, 30, 34],
       [42, 46, 50]])
```

Comment: Thanks Oliver. I will go to read the references, I have an image of three layers (imported from jpg image) for which I want to extract the fft on sliding windows. `In [34]: img.shape`
`Out[34]: (2119, 4125, 3)`. Will see if I can make it work out..